# Mysql error 1062 even when creating a table with one column only that is not unique

Tags: mysql-error-1062

I'm trying to create a table with one column only that is not unique.
The error encountered is error code 1062 [add table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vilkB.png)

I'm trying to create a table with one column only. I'm expecting to have a new table with one column.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Add the "mysql" and perhaps "sql" tags to your question. Include the code you run and the output you get. Use text for that, not images, so (hint!!) it can be searched online.